# Excel VBA - in a list, if cell equals specific value then

Tags: vba, excel

I started working on some code, and it works, but I feel like it could be done more effiently. Below is a portion of it to show what I'm doing. To simplify the idea, I've made it here so if the cell in column M is A, B, or C, it puts a 1 in column L. If column M is a D, E, or F, it puts a 2 in column L. And if column M is a G, H, or I, it puts a 3 in column L.

Is there an easier way to do this than how I'm doing it? I'm going to be dealing with a couple hundred possible values. [Alex P](https://stackoverflow.com/users/235442/alex-p) suggested I build a reference table. I've never done that before, so I'm not sure if that's my best bet or not.

```
Sub ChangeTest()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    LastRow = Range("M" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To LastRow
        If Range("M" & i).Value = "A" Or Range("M" & i).Value = "B" Or Range("M" & i).Value = "C" Then
        Range("L" & i).Value = "1"
        End If
        If Range("M" & i).Value = "D" Or Range("M" & i).Value = "E" Or Range("M" & i).Value = "F" Then
        Range("L" & i).Value = "2"
        End If
        If Range("M" & i).Value = "G" Or Range("M" & i).Value = "H" Or Range("M" & i).Value = "I" Then
        Range("L" & i).Value = "3"
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: "Simplifying" your code works well for [so]. On this site however, you'll get much more useful feedback if you include your *real, actual, working* code. Try it next time! (please don't edit your question in such a way that would invalidate already-given answers) - see [a guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/5777/23788) for more information.

Comment: I posted this on Stack Overflow first, and I was told to post it here. And I got a site warning for pasting my real, actual, working code because it said most of my post was code. So I thought because of that, and just so everyone would be able to make more sense out of it, I made it much simpler and shorter.

Comment: SO folks were right - getting feedback on any/all aspects of your code happens on Code Review, not SO. I've never seen that warning though, but the post length limit on CR is pretty much *double* that of SO, and you should be fine if your post *presents* the code to the reviewers, i.e. explains what's going on and why - as you've done here.

Comment: [cross-posted from Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40727837/1188513)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't know if it would be faster, but it would look cleaner to use a Select.

```
Sub ChangeTest()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
      LastRow = Range("M" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
      For i = 2 To LastRow
        Select Case Range("M" & i)
          Case "A", "B", "C"
            Range("L" & i) = "1"
          Case "D","E","F"
            Range("L" & i) = "2"
          Case "G","H","I"
            Range("L" & i) = "3"
        End Select
      Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: This looks good. There's going to be lots of cases, so I'm hoping this isn't too slow. It might take me a few days to fully implement.

Comment: At least this way, it is much faster to add a new condition rather than using it in an IF.

Comment: @Robby - If this helped, please mark as the answer.

Comment: I haven't been able to implement it yet. Sorry. I'm out of the office for a few days.